# OSRM ignoring roads without empty names

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine, map-matching

I want to ignore all roads that have an empty 'name' field when running match in OSRM. I have looked through the documentation, including the profiles, and cannot seem to figure it out. Is this something I can do in a custom profile lua file? Or something else?